# Deck Transformations Question

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, normal-subgroups, covering-spaces, fundamental-groups

Using the Hatcher's notation on proposition 1.39. Let $G(\tilde{X}):=\{ \varphi: \tilde{X} \to \tilde{X} \; \mathrm{Isomorphism} \}$ be the Deck transformation group for the covering space $p: \tilde{X} \to X$.

**Question:** Could someone please explain to me why 
$$G(\tilde{X})\cong \pi_1(X,x_0)/p_*(\pi_1(\tilde{X},\tilde{x_0}))$$
holds just when the covering $\tilde{X}$ is a normal covering? Please provide a counterexample when this does not hold when the covering is **not** normal.

Many thanks.

Comment: If the covering is not normal, how can you talk about a group isomorphism?

Comment: Such a simple but really precise and correct answer. Thanks!